# Sphinxsearch 2.3.2-beta version for OSX

Tags: macos, sphinx, macos-high-sierra

I want to install 2.3.2-beta version on my Mac book pro (sierra) and I couldn't find the setup file in any site.

Could you please help me to install it on my OSX?

I also ask this question on sphinxsearch forums, but no one answered me.

Also there is a macOS binary file in this page
http://sphinxsearch.com/downloads/current/

But I do not know how to install it on my mac.
I can install this version too, if I could install the binaries. But I don't know how.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: There should be the binaries in 'bin' dir once you unarchive that. Just use them, you can put them where you wish (/usr/bin/ , /usr/local/bin/ or ~/Applications/ etc.), the binaries are stand-alone and don't need anything nearby. BTW in Manticore (fork of Sphinx) recently few osx-related bugs were fixed - https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/releasenotes.html#version-2-6-2-ga-23-february-2018

Comment: Thanks a lot. And how to run them? or tell the OS to detect them? And also what about other paths inside sphinx.conf file? I can locate them where I want, too?

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-searchd and http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-indexer should answer the question how to run them. Yes, you can specify the paths in sphinx.conf as you want, they don't need to point to any specific location. You can also use this https://manticoresearch.com/2018/02/19/minimal-configuration-to-play-with-manticoresearch/ as a getting started guide, looks like it may be helpful to you (it's for Manticore, but should run as well for Sphinx)

Comment: Thanks. Helped me a lot. Please write an answer and I vote you up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be the binaries in 'bin' dir once you unarchive that. Just use them, you can put them where you wish (/usr/bin/ , /usr/local/bin/ or ~/Applications/ etc.), the binaries are stand-alone and don't need anything nearby. BTW in Manticore (fork of Sphinx) few osx-related bugs were [fixed](https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/releasenotes.html#version-2-6-2-ga-23-february-2018) recently, so you may prefer to use that instead.

Please read https://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-searchd and https://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#ref-indexer on how to run the binaries. As for the paths in your sphinx config file - you can change them as you want, they don't need to point to any specific location. You can also use [this](https://manticoresearch.com/2018/02/19/minimal-configuration-to-play-with-manticoresearch/) as a getting started guide, looks like it may be helpful to you (it's for Manticore, but should work as well for Sphinx)